# Didn't find class "com.apps.mobileapps.androidx" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, androidx, android-multidex

I had this error message when running my android apps, it looks like error is related to multi-dexing because it tries to find a class in my DexPathList and fails

```
2019-11-03 23:10:02.965 13828-13828/com.apps.mobileapps/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.apps.mobileapps.androidx" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.apps.mobileapps-muEimjMtTACdHZQnV9kDoQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.apps.mobileapps-muEimjMtTACdHZQnV9kDoQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.apps.mobileapps-muEimjMtTACdHZQnV9kDoQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:228)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:733)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:812)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1034)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2357)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5821)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:200)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1673)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to dsiable **Instant Run**

sometimes problem is AndroidStudio is tying to use "Instant Run" instead of compiling and installing a fresh APK.

Disable **Instant Run** `from File -> Settings -> Build,Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run`